# speed up data transfer from SQL server to application

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have build an application that handles data stored in a MS SQL server database.
This server is hosted externally of our company and has to be connected to via SSH because of company rules.

On a regular working day it takes about 7 minutes to retrieve a list of data, while it takes less than one minute to do the same outside office hours.

The database is relatively simple. There are 3 main tables which have a relation to each other on one field which is also set as primary key.
These tables have relations with several other small tables where lists are stored.
So the fields in the main tables are integer fields related to a small table where that integer points to a text field.

I'm trying to figure out why it takes 7 minutes during office hours and less than one 1 outside office hours.

There are about 12 users.

Anyone have some tips for me?

rg,
Eric

Comment: Are you running sql or stored procedure to retrieve the data? Try to check the plans for query during off hours as well as during main hours. When query run during main hours try to see what it is waiting on, netwrok could pose some delay if there is lots of traffic but 7 minute to 1 minute diff looks like a big diff.

Comment: SQL code is sent to the server then the wait starts for the data.

Comment: If there's a lot of data being transferred then it's likely to depend on how heavily your network is being utilized in and out of office hours.